# MVC, post partial model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have object A which has a `List<ObjectB>`
ObjectB has several properties. `Id`, `Mandatory`, `Name` etc.

So I return a viewmodel (`ObjectA`) and have this in my razor:

```
@model ObjectA
<div>
<div>@Html.HiddenFor(m => ObjectA.ObjectC.ID)
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => ObjectA.ObjectC.Name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => ObjectA.ObjectC.Name)
        </dd>
    </dl></div>
    // display stuff from objectA
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        foreach (var ft in ObjectA.ObjectB)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(c => ft.ID)
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                @if (ft.Mandatory)
                {
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(c => ft.Mandatory, new { id = ft.ID, disabled = "disabled" })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(c => ft.Mandatory)
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(c => ft.Mandatory, new { id = ft.ID })
                }
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in my Controller I tried as input parameter:
`List<ObjectB> items`
but it was null. Now I know I could try `FormCollection` which I did and found out that `form.Get("ft.id")` had the amount of items in de objectB list. same for mandatory. **But I'd like it strong typed**. Either:

1 object A with all subobjects of type B

2 a list/ienumerable of type objectB.

It's probably a small thing, but I can't see it right now.

**edit** my model:

```
public class ObjectA : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObjectC DisplayOnly { get; internal set; }

    public List<ObjectB> Features { get; set; }
}
```

My view: (see above)
My controller:

```
[Route("Details/{id:int}")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(ObjectA vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        int hid = Convert.ToInt32(RouteData.Values["id"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you post your model `ObjectA`, at Html level I don't see any reason for the browser to send all the fields but only those present in the Html form. So it doesn't make much sense trying to receive `List<ObjectB>` as input in your controller.

Comment: All props of `ObjectA` are just there to display. And the ObjectB is a sort of extended select list. It's id, mandatory, name, price, description etc. So only the changes of objectB is needed. But a full objectA with everything is okay too. Tried that and was null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code, it will render the checkbox input elements with name attribute values set to `ft.Mandatory`. When the form is submitted, model binder has no idea where to map this to because it does not match with the view model property names/property hierarchy. For model binding to work, the names of input should match with the parameter class's property name.

You can use **Editor Templates** to handle this use case.

Create a folder called `EditorTemplates` in `~/Views/Shared` or `~/Views/YourControllerName` and create a new view and give it the same name as your class name which you are using to represent the data needed for the checkbox. In your case it will be `ObjectB.cshtml`

Now make this view strongly typed to `OptionB` and render the checkbox and hidden input.

```
@model OptionB
<div>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Mandatory)
    @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.Id)
</div>
```

Remember, the ***browser will not send the values of disabled form elements*** when the form is submitted.

Now in your main view, you can call `EditorFor` helper method.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{   
    @Html.EditorFor(a=>a.OptionBList)
    <button type="submit">Send form</button>
}
```

This will render the checkboxes with name attribute values like this (*Assuming you have 3 items in OptionBList*) , along with hidden inputs for checkboxes

```
Options[0].Mandatory
Options[1].Mandatory
Options[2].Mandatory
```

Now you can simply use OptionA as the parameter of your HttpPost action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(OptionA model)
{
   foreach(var item in model.OptionBList)
   {
     //check item.Mandatory and item.Id
   }
   //to do : return something
}
```

Comment: But I'd like to receive a list with all checked checkboxes. Some are mandatory so they are selected by default and made readonly/disabled. But I need those too in my controller action.

Comment: This will give all of checkboxes (one for each item in the OptionBList collecction). See my update to the answer. Disabled checkboxes won't be submitted.

Comment: Your editor template seems to work. I did had to add constructor to the model with no input parameter. But it posts back now and the list is not null.